# Two column list with

Tags: tables, lists, columns

How can I make a list of two columns with a border and a vertical line separating the two columns as an image?
I've tried with tabular and mini page but nothing works properly! Can someone show me how to do this?

Example:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and maybe describe what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering

With \verb|minipage|s:\bigskip

\fboxsep=.6em
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{.25\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item   
\item
\end{itemize}   
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{.25\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\end{itemize}   
\end{minipage}}

\bigskip With \verb|tabular|:\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\item
\end{itemize}}& 
\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip With \verb|\parbox| alone:\bigskip

\fbox{\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\item
\end{itemize}} \vrule%
\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\end{itemize}}}

\end{document}
```

But may be you do not need/want an itemize enviroment, but only a compact list. Then you can make simply lines within `p{}` columns  with `\newline` and start each line with `\textbullet{}` or anything else:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbullet{} Bla bla bla ... \newline
\textbullet{} \newline
\textbullet{} \newline  & 
\rule[.25em]{.25em}{.25em} Bla bla bla ... \newline
\rule[.25em]{.25em}{.25em} \newline  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\begin{document}
\framebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{%
\begin{Bitemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{Bitemize}}%
\framebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{%
\begin{Bitemize}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\end{Bitemize}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed, multicol, blindtext, textcomp, lmodern}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\begin{framed}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \item Punkt
    \end{itemize}
  \end{multicols}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]