# two columns with visible separating line

Tags: tables, pdftex, multicolumn

I tried for about 30 minutes, but could not find a solution that works for such a simple task. how do I do this?

I managed to somehow make two columns but the separating line ends right away, I need it to go all the way to the end of the page.

thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNuNS.jpg)

Comment: Are these completly separated columns? What happens if the left column is full? Will the text then continue in the right colum or in the left column of a new page? Please add some clarifications, also ragarding the actual contents of the columns.

Comment: I need empty space on both columns. I do not fully understand what you are asking, but basically what I need is what's in the picture when I print out the pdf. It says Quiz on top and then columns with a separating line. and empty space provided for students' answers. I am just trying to prepare a quiz template and as it seems, after now 2 hours of search, there is no such example anywhere!

Comment: Probably you can make use of multicols package and its column separation rule.

Comment: Try `\columnseprule=0.5pt` (for example).  Works with twocolumn, multicols, paracol etc.

Comment: there is a column separating line but it is ending right away. I need it to go down all the way, to the end of the page. I need empty spaces on both columns.

Comment: Probably take a look at the multicolrule package and the extend-fill option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `multicolrule` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicolrule}
\columnseprule=0.5pt
\SetMCRule{line-style=solid,extend-fill}
\begin{document}
\centering{QUIZ}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Q1 
\columnbreak

Q2
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, this will do!

Answer (score 0):

This is already available on the site created by @Fran ---- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185663/197451

Have a look and see if this is what you wanted

The output will be as below

[image]

### The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\centering

With \verb|minipage|s:\bigskip

\fboxsep=.6em
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{.25\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item   
\item
\end{itemize}   
\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][2cm][t]{.25\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\end{itemize}   
\end{minipage}}

\bigskip With \verb|tabular|:\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\item
\end{itemize}}& 
\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\end{itemize}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip With \verb|\parbox| alone:\bigskip

\fbox{\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\item
\end{itemize}} \vrule%
\parbox[t]{0.25\textwidth}{
\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla bla ...
\item
\end{itemize}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks but no. this just gives a box. I don't want a box, I just want two columns and separating line all the way end of the page. Just like the photo.

Comment: The box can be removed by simply skipping the '\hline' commands and by not having a '|' between the delimiters. For eg. \begin{tabular}{l|l} can be used in place of \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}